# Spring Security : Custom filter (JwtAuthenticationFilter) is being called even when i have set specific endpoints to permitAll property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

i have used spring security to secure my endpoints now i am configuring my web app to expose specific end points so that no custom filter is being applied on those end point but even though i have given permitAll property too these endpoints custom filters are being applied on these end points. i have also noticed a behavious that even if i remove the property of addFilterBefore from my config class such that there is no mentioning of JwtAuthenticationFiter then also this filter is being executed upon call of these end points.

endpoints i want to expose are (/api/users/generate-token) post method
this is to generate token for the first time user logs in and it makes no sense to apply jwt autthentication filter on this request

also endpoint (api/user/register) for user to sign up  here also it makes no sense to apply jwt autthentication filter on this request

i am new to java and spring 6 and i am stuck badly and am not able to make any progress from past 3 days.

your help is very much appreciated.

i tried to add security filter chain to expose these particular end points and add JwtAuthenticationFilter before every other endpoint request.

and i was expecting to get a generated token as a response when i make post request to "/api/users/generate-token" with correct credentials.

```
SecurityConfig class
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;


    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoderConfig passwordEncoderConfig;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;





    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .csrf(csrf->csrf.disable())
                .cors(cors->cors.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        auth->auth.requestMatchers("/api/users/generate-token", "/api/users/register").permitAll()
                                  .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                                  .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .exceptionHandling((ex)->ex.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                .sessionManagement((session)->session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        http
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        System.out.println("http configuration is being used");
//


        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoderConfig.passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

```
JwtAuthenticationFilter class
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        System.out.println("jwt authentication fliter is being called");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        if(requestTokenHeader!=null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer")){
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = this.jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwtToken);
            }catch (ExpiredJwtException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("jwt token expired");

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("error");
            }

        }else {
            System.out.println("invalid or token doesn't start with Bearer");
        }
        //validate
        if(username!=null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()==null){
            final UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (this.jwtUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)){
                //token is valid
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthentication);
            }else {
                System.out.println("invalid token");
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
        }

    }
}
```

```
JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint class
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorised : Server");
    }
}
```

```
Controller class

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class AuthenticateController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;


    @PostMapping("/generate-token")
    public ResponseEntity<JwtResponse> generateToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest jwtRequest) throws Exception {
        try{
            System.out.println(jwtRequest.getUsername());
            System.out.println(jwtRequest.getPassword());
            authenticate(jwtRequest.getUsername(),jwtRequest.getPassword());
            System.out.println("authentication successful");

        }catch (UserNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new UserNotFoundException("user not found ");
        }

        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(jwtRequest.getUsername());
        String token = this.jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        System.out.println(token+"hey");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new JwtResponse(token), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        try{
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        }catch (DisabledException e){
            throw new Exception("user disabled : "+e.getMessage());
        }catch (BadCredentialsException e){
            throw new Exception("bad user credentials : "+e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

please let me know if you need any other code block also!

Comment: hi Akash, Can you please provide other classes like UserServiceDetailsImpl, JwtUtils.   
 It will be better if you can upload your code to GitHub and provide the link

Comment: using jwts as sessions is dangerous and should not be done, stop following bad tutorials from people that dont know security and instead read the spring security documentation and implement security correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Spring Security has no knowledge that jwtAuthenticationFilter is an authentication filter - you extend it from OncePerRequestFilter. Have you tried extending BasicAuthenticationFilter or AuthenticationFilter ?

There is also another option - you can specify allowed urls in the filter itself.